# How do I define a method which takes a lambda as a parameter and reduce code

Tags: java, methods, lambda, collections, extension-methods

An abstract class in which methods

```
public abstract class ListDataSource<T extends List<Long>> implements DataSourceList {

    private final T list;
    private final Random random;
    private final long DATA = 5;

    public ListDataSource(int size) {
        this.list = initializeList();
        this.populateData(size);
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    protected void populateData(int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list.add((long) i);
        }
    }

    protected abstract T initializeList();

    @Override
    public long addToTheBegin() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.add(0, DATA);
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return finish - start;
    }

    @Override
    public long addToMiddle() {
        int middle = list.size() / 2;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.add(middle, DATA);
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return finish - start;
    }

    @Override
    public long addToEnd() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.add(DATA);
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return finish - start;
    }

    @Override
    public long searchValue() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.get((int)DATA);
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return finish - start;
    }

    @Override
    public long removeFromBegin() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.remove(0);
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return finish - start;
    }

    @Override
    public long removeFromMiddle() {
        int middle = list.size() / 2;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.remove(middle);
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return finish - start;
    }

    @Override
    public long removeFromEnd() {
        int size = list.size();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        list.remove(size - 1);
        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return finish - start;
    }
}
```

and reduce code

метод который вычисляет время работы операций с колекцией и в отдельном потоке отпрявляет brodcast

```
public void colculaitTime (int size) {
    
    ArrayListDataSource arrayListData = new ArrayListDataSource(size);

     new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
    long listdata = arrayListData.addToTheBegin();
    Intent intentToSend = new Intent(SIMPLE_ACTION);
    intentToSend.putExtra(Util.ARRAY_TIME_ADD_TO_THE_BEGIN, listdata);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intentToSend);
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
    long listdata_1 = arrayListData.addToMiddle();
    Intent intentToSend_1 = new Intent(SIMPLE_ACTION);
    intentToSend_1.putExtra(Util.ARRAY_TIME_ADD_TO_MIDDLE, listdata_1);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intentToSend_1);
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
    long listdata_2 = arrayListData.addToEnd();
    Intent intentToSend_2 = new Intent(SIMPLE_ACTION);
    intentToSend_2.putExtra(Util.ARRAY_TIME_ADD_TO_END, listdata_2);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intentToSend_2);
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() {
    long listdata_3 = arrayListData.searchValue();
    Intent intentToSend_3 = new Intent(SIMPLE_ACTION);
    intentToSend_3.putExtra(Util.ARRAY_TIME_TO_VALUE, listdata_3);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intentToSend_3);
                }
            }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
    long listdata_4 = arrayListData.removeFromBegin();
    Intent intentToSend_4 = new Intent(SIMPLE_ACTION);
    intentToSend_4.putExtra(Util.ARRAY_TIME_R_F_BEGIN, listdata_4);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intentToSend_4);
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
    long listdata_5 = arrayListData.removeFromMiddle();
    Intent intentToSend_5 = new Intent(SIMPLE_ACTION);
    intentToSend_5.putExtra(Util.ARRAY_TIME_R_F_MIDDLE, listdata_5);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intentToSend_5);
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
    long listdata_6 = arrayListData.removeFromEnd();
    Intent intentToSend_6 = new Intent(SIMPLE_ACTION);
    intentToSend_6.putExtra(Util.ARRAY_TIME_R_F_END, listdata_6);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intentToSend_6);
        }
    }).start();


}
```

I am new to java how can I wrap repetitive code in blocks into one method. I understand the parameters but each block has a different method I am stumped.

Comment: Are you looking for just how to define a runnable using a lambda?

Comment: new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() {
    long listdata_4 = arrayListData.removeFromBegin();
    Intent intentToSend_4 = new Intent(SIMPLE_ACTION);
    intentToSend_4.putExtra(Util.ARRAY_TIME_R_F_BEGIN, listdata_4);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intentToSend_4);
        }
    }).start();

Comment: make this code into a method

Comment: Describe your requirement *in English* or post your question on https://ru.stackoverflow.com/